# My Android app does not support all Android Devices on google play

Tags: android

I have new Android App published on Google Play. What should I add Or remove from manifest file so it must be support all android phones and tabs.

Comment: Have you Created different layouts for different screens in res folder?

Comment: added supports screentypes in manifest?

Comment: Please post your manifest. I also recommend you read this as well if you have not done so already: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html  Even if you do manage to get all devices supported, your app may not scale correctly without different layouts.

Comment: Yes I have created different layout folders(xhdpi,hdpi,mdpi,ldpi) in res folder. Also I added supports screentypes. My target is to support all android devices.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup minSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="1"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

But you need to make shure that your app will work correct on all devices.

Comment: I have done already but it looks screen resolution issue. What should I do to support all screens.

Comment: You can browse google ioshed project. It work great on phones and tablets, and support different resolutions. https://code.google.com/p/iosched/

Answer (score 1):

Android xml:

API-compatibility:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="1"
          android:targetSdkVersion="~"/>
```

Display-compatibility:

```
    <supports-screens 
            android:xlargeScreens="true"
            android:largeScreens="true" 
            android:normalScreens="true" 
            android:smallScreens="true" 
            android:anyDensity="true"  
        />
```

In the Google Play developer console, select your application, go to 'APK', and make sure no devices are excluded.

I just uploaded a test application, and I managed to support 4400 of 4444 devices. The excluded ones were some Google TV devices, and other cryptic apparatuses. I think that is good enough...

Answer (score 0):

set the target sdk values in AndroidManifest.XML of your project

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

Yous should keep android:minSdkVersion as 1 and android:targetSdkVersion as 19 (Android KitKat)
Refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: I have done already but it is looking screen resolution issue. What should I do support all screens.

Comment: In your layout files, use fill_parent and wrap_content to specify the width and height of views, don't specify in dp. If it still doesn't look proper, please share you layout xml files